# *this parameter to a function

Tags: c++, this

I understand what *this->function* does but the code i'm looking at has 
function_name(*this,param1,param2) and I'm not to clear on what that is supposed to do.

we are passing pointer to the object being worked on and two parameters to the function?

Comment: You're passing the current object and two other parameters to a third function.

Comment: _*this_ represents the _value_ of the current object

Comment: `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`, so you are basically already using `*this`, just don't know it

Answer (score 2):

**`*this`** is not a pointer, it is the current object `this` pointed to.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, `*this` is when you dereference the pointer, it is special in that it is the current object you are "inside" so to speak

Comment: I know and I did not say that `this` is not a pointer.

Comment: your answer is just a little misleading to read

Comment: you are kind of right, and I should make `*this` part in bold. But I could not because the triple stars.

Comment: @JohnSmith did that for you :D

Answer (score 2):

Your function:

```
function_name(*this,param1,param2)
```

takes, as first parameter, a `T` or `T&` (or `const T&`) (with `T` = type of the object `this` points to). The pointers `this` is being dereferenced, and like any pointer, the expression `*x` points to the *value* being pointed by `x`.